# Get current URL in Laravel without parsing?

Tags: laravel

It's quite easy to get the current URL:

```
Request::url()
```

This would return something like:

```
http://localhost/some/or/other/path
```

However, if I want an easy way to get only:

```
some/or/other/path
```

What would I do? Is there a way to do this without parse_url? I.e. Does Laravel have an inherent built-in way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about [`Request::path()`](http://laravel.com/docs/requests#request-information)?

```php
$uri = Request::path();
```

Answer (score 1):

In my codes I am using code below (Laravel version 4)

```
Request::url();
```